# Unable to show the boundedness of the map $\varphi$ from $\hat M$ to the Hilbert space $H_\tau$

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\tau$ be a faithful normal state. Let $(\pi_\tau,H_\tau)$ be the GNS representation of $M$ with respect to $\tau$, that is, $\pi_\tau: M \to B(H_\tau)$ is a $*$-homomorphism. Since $\tau$ is faithful, we can view $M$ as a dense subspace of $H_\tau$. We use the notation $\hat x$ when we want to stress the point that $x$ is considered as an element of $H_\tau$.
Let $x \in M$. Now define $R_x: \hat M \to H_\tau$ by $R_x(\hat y)=\hat {yx}$ for all $y \in M$. Recall that the inner product $\langle,\rangle$ defined on $\hat M$ with respect to which $H_\tau$ is the completion is defined as
$$\langle \hat x,\hat y\rangle=\tau(x^*y),~~\forall ~x,y \in M.$$
Now notice that $R_x$ is bounded. This is because,
$$\|R_x(\hat y)\|^2=\|\hat{yx}\|^2=\langle \hat {yx},\hat {yx}\rangle=\tau(x^*y^*xy)=\tau(yxx^*y^*)\le \|x^*x\|\tau(y^*y)=\|x\|^2\|y\|^2.$$
Now since $R_x$ is bounded and $\hat M$ is dense in $H_\tau$, we can extend $R_x$ to $H_\tau$. Call it again $R_x$ and taking $R_x \in B(H_\tau)$.
Let $\theta \in H_\tau$. Now define $\varphi: \hat M \to H_\tau$ by
$$\varphi(\hat x)=R_x(\theta),~~\forall~ x \in M.$$ Now I am unable to show that $\varphi$ is bounded and also if not bounded I am unable to find counterexamples. Please help me to solve this.  Thank you.

Comment: A comment about notation: when you write $\|Rx(\hat y)\|\leq\|x\|\,\|y\|$, the norm for $x$ is the operator norm of $M$, while the norm for $y$ is the $2$-norm from $\tau$. It's probably better to write $\|\hat y\|$ or $\|y\|_2$.

Comment: Next exercise: Show that $\varphi$ is bounded if and only if $\theta\in \hat M$, and if $\theta=\hat y$, then $\varphi=\pi_\tau(y)$. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ is a II$_1$-factor with trace $\tau$, and let $\{p_n\}$ be a pairwise orthogonal sequence of projections with $\tau(p_n)=2^{-n}$. Define
$$
\theta=\sum_k\sqrt k\,\hat p_k.
$$
This sum converges because the $\hat p_k$ are pairwise orthgonal and
$$
\|\theta\|_2^2=\sum_kk\,2^{-k}=2.
$$
Let
$$
x_n=2^{n/2}\,\hat p_n.
$$
Then, for all $n$.
$$
\|\hat x_n\|^2_2=2^n\,\tau(p_n)=1.
$$
And
$$
\|\phi(\hat x_n)\|_2=\|R_{x_n}(\theta)\|_2=\sqrt n\,2^{n/2}\,\|\hat p_n\|_2
=\sqrt n\,2^{n/2}\,\tau(p_n)^{1/2}=\sqrt n. 
$$
Hence $\phi$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, Sir I am not familiar with $II_1$ factors. Can you please help with an example of such $M$, so that I can get an intuitive idea? If possible. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't know the theory, you won't get intuition from an example. I could tell you that you take any infinite-conjugacy-class group, like $\mathbb F_2$, consider the left regular representation $\rho$, and define $M=\rho(\mathbb F_2)''$; but you'll get zero intuition from it. But let me ask you: what examples of von Neumann algebras with faithful normal states do you know, other than the finite-dimensional ones?

Comment: An abelian von Neumann algebra $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$. I know this is a von Neumann algebra with faithful normal state.

Comment: Fair enough. Make sure to note that abelian von Neumann algebras are really far from the general thing. But take my example where $M=L^\infty[0,1]$, $\tau(f)=\int_0^1f$, and $p_n=1_{[2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad  I could help. To comment on something that you said before, note that $L^\infty(X)$ has a faithful normal state only if $X$ is $\sigma$-finite.